# Django custom Model method throws Attribute Error

Tags: django, django-models

I was really hoping I wouldn't have to resort to SO for this , but it's driving me crazy now so here goes...

```
# models.py
[...]
from datetime import datetime as dt

class Foo(models.Model):
    [...]
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_time']

    def is_fresh(self):
        if (dt.now() - self.date_time).seconds < settings.FOO_LIFESPAN:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s|%s %s' % ([...], self.date_time)
```

When I try to use the `is_fresh()` method I get `AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'is_fresh'`.

I've seen that others who have had this problem on SO have solved it by fixing the indentation. I am confident that that is not the case here (famous last words). I'm working in Eclipse and I haven't had any other sneaky indentation-related errors...

Any thoughts?

### EDIT

I'm using this as part of a Dajaxice/Dajax function.

```
# ajax.py

def seek_bar(request, name):
    # Other stuff goes here. I know that it works 100%
    foo_list = []
    [...]
    for receipt in receipts:
        foo_list.append((receipt.foos.all()[0], receipt.pk))
        [...]

    # Check freshness
    for (foo, bar) in foo_list:
        if foo.is_fresh():
            dajax.add_css_class('#timer_0%s' % bar, 'fresh')
        else:
            dajax.remove_css_class('#timer_0%s' % bar, 'fresh')
            dajax.add_css_class('#timer_0%s' % bar, 'stale')
```

Comment: Are you importing models? `from django.db import models`

Comment: Show us how you are using/calling the `is_fresh`. Also use `.total_seconds()` instead of `.seconds` if you want more precision.

Comment: can you show an example usage in your view ?

Comment: The question is how the list `foo_list` is built, this is your problem or probable root of the problem anyways.

Comment: I should add that it's not only throwing me this error when I call seek_bar(), but also when I call is_fresh() on a Foo object in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and I want to kick the wall!

The problem has to do with my file structure and how I was importing the model. I have two apps which share the same models.py, so I put it in a separate folder like so:

```
my_project/
        |
      backend/
            |
          models/
             - __init__.py
             - models.py
```

In ajax.py, I was importing Foo like this: `from my_project.backend.models import Foo, ...,`. It worked for everything I needed until `is_fresh()` came along. I just tried `from my_project.backend.models.models import Foo, ...,`, and lo and behold - it worked! And I feel silly...

If anyone can tell me why `...backend.models` worked for everything except my custom method, but I needed `...backend.models.models` for full functionality, it would be good to know.